# Equation for line normal to tangent of ellipse

Tags: 3d, ellipse

I know the center of an ellipse (cx, cy, cz). Radius in directions x,y and z respectively are rx, ry, rz. Given a point (X,Y,Z) on the ellipse how can I find the line perpendicular to the tangent of ellipse at the given point.
Kindly help.

Thanking you,
Vijitha

Comment: `math.stackexchange.com` You might get an answer here, but this source will be better for you in the future

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking...

The first step would be to convert what you know about the ellipse (its centre, the major / minor axis) into an equation defining the ellipse

You can then find the tangent by taking the derivative of the equation defining the ellipse.

Once you have the tangent then you can invert the slope, giving you a line perpendicular to the tangent line.